# Call block in template file

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

Is there some simple code I can add to my page.tpl.php to call a block directly from the template file?

- I cannot add modules to this site
- Users need to be able to edit the contents of the block themselves

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/26502

Comment: Yes, there is. But my answer is: you don't really want to do it. If you need to reprogram site but are required to avoid Drupal'd designed way of modifying sites, just quit this commission. It's not worth it. They are asking you to do things in a way that will almost certainly break and will make these breaks to look like your fault? Easier to pay penalties now, than to put work into it, and then pay them later anyway. **Put a region. Use module to govern user-editable blocks. Or quit before it's too late.**